# performance of WCF Service implemented with entity framework in my wcf service?

Tags: performance, entity-framework, wcf, visual-studio-2012

I am using visual studio 2012, previously when I was using entity framework directly in my application it was working fine, but now I have implemented entity framework in my wcf service and calling that service in my project, now it's taking much more time. Is there any tool or online service where we can test our wcf service

Comment: Consider posting your relevant codes as well, otherwise this will be too broad to answer.

Comment: what bindings are you using? is the wcf service on the same machine as the client / database? how long is *much more time* and how long was it before?

Comment: i am using basicHttpsBinding , no its on another machine, it was taking  20 sec before now its taking around 1 min.